# Trying to loop values from vuex store, if I inspect code it looks right but when I check checkboxes and radios it doesnt work

Tags: vue.js, vuex, tailwind-css

My vuex store array

```
    itemsToCheck: [
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_diskborste', title: 'Diskborste', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_diskborste', label: 'Check!', type: 'checkbox', url: require('../assets/diskborste.jpg'), alt: 'diskborste', value: 'tornfalksgrand2_diskborste_finns', additionalText: ''},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_disktrasa', title: 'Disktrasa', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_disktrasa', label: 'Check!', type: 'checkbox', url: require('../assets/disktrasa.png'), alt: 'disktrasa', value: 'tornfalksgrand2_disktrasa_finns', additionalText: ''},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_vaskskrapa', title: 'Vaskskrapa', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_vaskskrapa', label: 'Check!', type: 'checkbox', url: require('../assets/vaskskrapa.webp'), alt: 'vaskskrapa', value: 'tornfalksgrand2_vaskskrapa_finns', additionalText: ''},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_alloren', title: 'Alloren', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_alloren', label: 'Check!', type: 'checkbox', url: require('../assets/alloren.webp'), alt: 'alloren', value: 'tornfalksgrand2_alloren_finns', additionalText: 'Fyll på befintlig flaska, eller spä ut med lite vatten.'},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppgarn', title: 'Moppgarn', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppgarn', label1: 'Finns!', label2: 'Fattas!', type: 'radio', url: require('../assets/moppgarn.jpg'), alt: 'moppgarn', value1: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppgarn_finns', value2: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppgarn_fattas', additionalText: 'Om moppen är väldigt smutsig, bocka i "Fattas" så byter vi den senare.'},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppskaft', title: 'Moppskaft', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppskaft', label1: 'Finns!', label2: 'Fattas!', type: 'radio', url: require('../assets/moppskaft.jpg'), alt: 'moppskaft', value1: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppskaft_finns', value2: 'tornfalksgrand2_moppskaft_fattas', additionalText: ''},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_mopphink', title: 'Mopphink', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_mopphink', label1: 'Finns!', label2: 'Fattas!', type: 'radio', url: require('../assets/mopphink.jpg'), alt: 'mopphink', value1: 'tornfalksgrand2_mopphink_finns', value2: 'tornfalksgrand2_mopphink_fattas', additionalText: ''},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopborste', title: 'Sopborste', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopborste', label1: 'Finns!', label2: 'Fattas!', type: 'radio', url: require('../assets/sopborste.png'), alt: 'sopborste', value1: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopborste_finns', value2: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopborste_fattas', additionalText: ''},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopskyffel', title: 'Sopskyffel', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopskyffel', label1: 'Finns!', label2: 'Fattas!', type: 'radio', url: require('../assets/sopskyffel.png'), alt: 'sopskyffel', value1: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopskyffel_finns', value2: 'tornfalksgrand2_sopskyffel_fattas', additionalText: ''},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_lysror', title: 'Lysrör', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_lysror', label1: 'Hela!', label2: 'Trasiga', type: 'radio', url: require('../assets/lysror.jpg'), alt: 'lysror', value1: 'tornfalksgrand2_lysror_hela', value2: 'tornfalksgrand2_lysror_trasiga', additionalText: 'Se till att inga lysrör blinkar eller är trasiga.'},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_nodutgang', title: 'Nödutgång', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_nodutgang', label: 'Check!', type: 'checkbox', url: require('../assets/nodutgang.jpg'), alt: 'nodutgang', value: 'tornfalksgrand2_nodutgang_inte_blockerad', additionalText: 'Se till att nödutgången inte är blockerad.'},
      {id: 'tornfalksgrand2_proppskap', title: 'Proppskåp', name: 'tornfalksgrand2_proppskap', label: 'Check!', type: 'checkbox', url: require('../assets/proppskap.webp'), alt: 'proppskap', value: 'tornfalksgrand2_proppskap_hela', additionalText: 'Alla knapparna på proppskåpet ska peka uppåt.'}
    ],
```

In my data property

```
data () {
        return {
            selected: [],
            isChecked: this.initIsChecked()
        }
      },
```

My html loop

```
    <div class="max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg mb-8" v-for="item in $store.state.itemsToCheck" :key="item.id">
      <img class="w-full" :src="item.url" :alt="item.alt">
      <div class="px-6 py-4 text-center">
        <div class="font-bold text-xl mb-2">{{ item.title }}</div>
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
            <input v-if="item.type == 'checkbox'" :id="item.id" class="form-checkbox text-green-500 h-6 w-6" v-model="selected" :name="item.name" :type="item.type" v-bind:value="item.value">
            <label v-if="item.type == 'checkbox'" :for="item.id" class="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">{{ item.label }}</label>

            <input v-if="item.type == 'radio'" :id="item.id+'_finns'" class="form-checkbox text-green-500 h-6 w-6" v-model="selected" :name="item.name" :type="item.type" v-bind:value="item.value1">
            <label v-if="item.type == 'radio'" :for="item.id+'_finns'" class="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">{{ item.label1 }}</label>

            <input v-if="item.type == 'radio'" :id="item.name+'_fattas'" class="form-checkbox text-green-500 h-6 w-6" v-model="selected" :name="item.name" :type="item.type" v-bind:value="item.value2">
            <label v-if="item.type == 'radio'" :for="item.name+'_fattas'" class="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">{{ item.label2 }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="px-6 pt-4 pb-2">
        <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700 mr-2 mb-2 text-center">{{ item.additionalText }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

My output html

```
<div class="text-base text-center mt-4">{{ selected }}</div>
```

When I inspect the elements in devtools all names and values seems to be right
[image of chrome devtools inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGkiZ.png)

My problem is that I can check all checkboxes until I check the first radiobutton, then all checkboxes will be unchecked... Maybe I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies behind the v-model value of the radios and the checkboxes.
On the radios you have `v-model="selected"`
Which i think is correct.
But on the checkboxes, u have `v-model="selected"` again.
It might be the problem.

Comment: You where right, if I change the v-model on the radios it does'nt uncheck the checkboxes.  But I can only check one pair of radios, if I check the next pair it uncheck the previous radiobutton pair. What I'm trying to achieve is to keep track of all the checked items in the output array. The radiobuttons keep track of excisting item or missing item.